# Can you use "on-the-fly" column names in SQL WHERE clasue?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a bit rusty with my SQL.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
SELECT *, DATEADD(d, 1 ,dStartDateTime) dCloseDate
FROM EventItem 
WHERE dCloseDate > '1990-01-01 07:00:00.000'
```

But when I do that I get the error:

```
Invalid column name 'dCloseDate'.
```

Anyone know a way around that? I just want to do it to make my code more readable/maintainable.

Any advice as to why I shouldn't do it would also be appreciated :)

Comment: depending which SQL server you using i prefer using CTEs to do this kind of thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use “on-the-fly” column names in SQL WHERE clause. (You can in the `ORDER BY` clause.)  You have to subquery it, or repeat the expression

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, DATEADD(d, 1 ,dStartDateTime) dCloseDate
FROM EventItem
) SUBQ
WHERE dCloseDate > '1990-01-01 07:00:00.000'
```

-or-

```
SELECT *, DATEADD(d, 1 ,dStartDateTime) dCloseDate
FROM EventItem 
WHERE DATEADD(d, 1 ,dStartDateTime) > '1990-01-01 07:00:00.000'
```

#### Why you shouldn't do it?

Having said that, you are performing a function against your column dStartDateTime which requires a **table scan**.  Always perform functions on the other side, so that the value found can be tested against an index on `dStartDateTime` (datetime column).

```
SELECT *, DATEADD(d, 1 ,dStartDateTime) dCloseDate
FROM EventItem 
WHERE dStartDateTime > DATEADD(d, -1 ,'1990-01-01 07:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Excellent and fast answer! Thanks for that. One thing though, when you say, I should perform my functions on "on the other side", what do you mean? Do you mean in the WHERE claue, rather than the SELECT?

Comment: @Ev - I mean instead of doing a function on the date to compare with a value, do the function on the value (`the other side`) which ends up with.. just another value.  Now armed with a value, SQL Server can use indexes to quickly locate that (range)

Comment: Yes, the point about [not] applying functions to columns in `WHERE` clause (as well as in `ON` clause for that matter) is particularly useful, even if only as a reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use the name you gave in the AS clause.  Instead you have to repeat the expression in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *, DATEADD(d, 1 ,dStartDateTime) AS dCloseDate
FROM EventItem 
WHERE DATEADD(d, 1 ,dStartDateTime) > '1990-01-01 07:00:00.000'
```

Which doesn't add to the readability or maintainability.  But it is the only way top do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you cannot reference column aliases (dCloseDate, in your example) in where clauses (or group bys or order bys). It would be nice if you/we could, but MS SQL just doesn't support that.

Comment: You can use them in ORDER BY. In fact that is the recommended way to do it rather than column position.